# Angular: Unable to create Pagination loop

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

I'm calling an API that only lists 30 results as a response.  With multiple pages, I need to create a while loop that calls the api and stores the data for each call, until there are no pages left.

I've tried this a couple ways. I have a service that calls the API and returns the data. In my component I'm trying to call that service, get the data, and call it again, store more data, etc.

Currently I'm using .reduce to store the data and separate it into key / value pairs.

```
export class SectionDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private _freshServiceService: freshServiceService) { }

private ticketCounts: number[];
private ticketResponders: string[];
keyValMap = {};

ngOnInit() {
let thisPage = 1;
this._freshServiceService.fetchTickets(thisPage).subscribe
(
  data =>
  {
    while(data.length > 0){
       thisPage += 1;
       this.getTicketData(data);
    }
  },
  err=> {
    console.log(err);
    if(err.status == "500"){
      console.log('yes')
    }
  }
);
  }


private getTicketData(tickets: Ticket[]): void {
  this.keyValMap = tickets.reduce((x, y) => {
  {x[y.responder_name] = x[y.responder_name] + 1 || 1};
  return x;
  }, this.keyValMap); 

  this.ticketResponders = Object.keys(this.keyValMap);

  this.ticketCounts = Object.values(this.keyValMap);

console.log(this.ticketResponders);
console.log(this.ticketCounts);
}
}
```

Everything I've tried just crashes my app as it runs infinitely and never updates the "data" variable, or it doesn't update the page number. I don't know how to include the actual service call inside the while loop and subscribe to it AND change it every time it's called. is this possible?

Side note:, I realize the above code is not a solution obviously, as the while loop doesn't include the call. I'm not quite sure how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

First few points to mention:

- My pagination only contained the option for going previous or next page. No option for selecting any middle page.
- I used ngrx store for storing pagination related data and final result.
- I used mongodb with node at the backend.

Steps:

1. As soon as page loads I call my API to fetch 20 results. (By default all the data is by descending order by _id). I only fetch the data when user moves to a new page.
2. On every new result I stored the first and last _id of the document.
3. If a user clicks on next page, a new request is made to the API. In the query parameter of request I passed two attributes representing last id of the result and 'next'.
4. Similarly for previous page, first ID and 'prev' value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does kind of help, but I don't really want to show the actual pages, just grab the data off all of them and put them in a graph that I created.  My API doesn't give a "total pages" option so I had to put some logic in about how to go to the next page and determine if there is any data to continue. 

I also had to sort my data by name, and count the number of times that name occured (eg: Jeff has 12 tickets completed).     Unfortunately I'm just not sure how to make the call multiple times and store the data from multiple pages because I'm relatively new to coding in general.

Comment: Are you trying to display a graph like bar chart or line graph ?

Comment: A pie chart, which I was able to get working. I successfully pulled one page of data from the API but am unable to figure out how to do a loop or whatever I need to do to get the second page and store it's data.

Comment: Why can't you just query the complete data at once ?

Comment: The API only pulls 30 items at a time max. Typically there are about 90+ that need to be pulled. Is there a way to do that all at once on the typescript side?

Comment: It looks like you need to perform the query on backend side. And then you can pass the result to your frontend part.

Comment: Could you give me a starting point? Is that something I should do in C# or does it really matter? thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to perform the query on your DB. You can look in the docs for the DB or the library which you are using with C#. I have not used C#, so I can't help you there.